# C replacing html tags in a string

Tags: html, c, string, tags

Good day all, I currently have a program that searches a html file that contains large amounts of text which includes hyperlinks in it. At the moment, I am only able to print out the entire line of text, which includes the raw html tags which I am trying to avoid. Is there a way to do this?

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

Sample line of text in html file:

```
<a href="/cgi-bin/as-report?as=AS41299&view=2.0">S/N1</a> Blahblahblah
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
S/N1 Blahblahblah
```

My code so far:

```
            while (!feof(fp)) {
                memset(buffer, 0, buflen+1);
                fgets(buffer, buflen, fp);

                    if (strstr(buffer, asnumber)) {
                        printf("\"%s\"\n", buffer);
                    }
            }
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can establish a context that tells you whether you are inside a tag or not and then filter your sring based on that context:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    void filter(char *str)
    {
        char *p = str;
        int tag = 0;

        while (*str) {
            if (*str == '<') tag = 1;        
            if (!tag) *p++ = *str;        
            if (*str == '>') tag = 0;
            str++;
        }

        *p = '\0';
    }

    int main()
    {
        char line[] = "Read <a href=\"x.html\">more <b>here</b></a>.";
        puts(line);
        filter(line);
        puts(line);

        return 0;
    }
```

This will work on well-formed HTML strings that properly escape all angle brackets that are not tag delimiters. If the line begins with a trailing open tag from the previous line, the rest of that tag will be printed.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was trying to achieve. I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `strstr`, which returns a pointer to the first instance of the search string.

```
char line[] = "<a href=\"/cgi-bin/as-report?as=AS41299&view=2.0\">S/N1</a> Blahblahblah";
printf( "line = %s\n", line );
char *line_notag = strstr(line, "</a>") + strlen("</a>"); // <-- Find the first position of the html end tag </a>, then move pass that tag to get the real string.
printf( "line_notag = %s\n", line_notag ); // line_notag =  Blahblahblah
```

Comment: `strstr` will find exact matches. I think the OP is interested in a solution that strips all tags, regardless of content. Also: have you tried your solution? It strips `S/N1` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, I am indeed only trying to remove the html tags.